# AWS role and user have not any policy,why I still can access K8s cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

My question: I have not any permission,why I can access K8s

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ kubectl get deployment --namespace=development
No resources found in development namespace.
```

---

Things below are my configuration.

```
$ cat ~/.kube/config 
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: <my certificate-authority-data>
    server: https://2C1A77626A2087EBA1D1123EA9398DAF.gr7.ap-northeast-1.eks.amazonaws.com
  name: arn:aws:eks:ap-northeast-1:056844949861:cluster/eksworkshop-eksctl
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: arn:aws:eks:ap-northeast-1:056844949861:cluster/eksworkshop-eksctl
    user: arn:aws:eks:ap-northeast-1:056844949861:cluster/eksworkshop-eksctl
  name: arn:aws:eks:ap-northeast-1:056844949861:cluster/eksworkshop-eksctl
current-context: arn:aws:eks:ap-northeast-1:056844949861:cluster/eksworkshop-eksctl
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: arn:aws:eks:ap-northeast-1:056844949861:cluster/eksworkshop-eksctl
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - --region
      - ap-northeast-1
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
      - eksworkshop-eksctl
      - --role
      - arn:aws:iam::056844949861:role/k8sDev
      command: aws
```

Here are my role and , nothing in Permissions:
[image]
[image]

Here is my user, just inline policy here:
[image]

here are my group and content of inline policy:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are able to access it is because the IAM user you are accessing the cluster is the same as the one used to create the cluster. The [documenation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html) states:

> When you create an Amazon EKS cluster, the IAM entity user or role,
> such as a federated user that creates the cluster, is automatically
> granted system:masters permissions in the cluster's RBAC
> configuration.

In EKS, IAM users are used for authentication, but IAM roles do not control authorization. Authorization is still handled through the kubernetes RBAC system.